# What is じゃ in じゃない?

Tags: particles, contractions, particle-で, particle-は, copula

Since there is possibility of "じゃありません" instead of "じゃないです" (which is logical, given "ありません" is polite "ない"), and it also seemed that I have seen "じゃ" used without "ない", I'd like to ask, what does "じゃ" exactly mean? It looks like some kind of particle which was used in old Japanese but is not used anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a contraction of `では` (particle `で`, which has various uses, and the topic marker `は`). It is not particularly related to classical Japanese, and is not used only with negation.

Comment: But why is it used to sign letters? For instance, I once received a letter that ended, じゃ, (name). And why is it used to end sentences?

Comment: Only the valediction じゃ is related to では; the copula じゃ is from a (only slightly different) etymology.

Comment: @ixtmixilix That is ellipsis. The reader is expected to reconstruct what comes after it, which is omitted.

Comment: @ZhenLin When you start analyzing `で` into its parts, it is not even clear whether it is a copula or it includes a copula. `で` comes from `にて`, and if you want to claim that `で` is (or includes) a copula, then the only reasonable thing you can do is to claim that `に` is the source of the copula. I don't know how much you can push that idea, but to me, it is more natural to consider that a nominal predicate in Japanese requires dative case and does not necessarily require a copula. For the part that nominal predicates require dative case, you can observe it the construction `...になる`.

Comment: @ZhenLin I realized that there is an entirely different `じゃ`, which is a copula, and is used by elder people or is a 役割語: `わらわは織姫じゃ。` Are you mentioning that? Then, I don't know the origin of it (but probably it's from `である`, which in turn is from `にてある`), and what you wrote may be right.

Comment: @sawa: Yes, the 役割語 (or dialectal) じゃ is precisely what I meant.

Comment: @ixtmixilix You can use じゃ as an informal way to say 'bye'. In English, it's similar to something like "well then (I'll be on my way)". But it feels more like "later!" or "cya!".

Sometimes, you'll also here variations それじゃ！ じゃね！or じゃな！

Comment: Can anyone clarify the level of difference in politeness/nuances between じゃありません and ではありいません?

Comment: @CptSupermrkt `ではありいません` is ungrammatical. If you meant `ではありません`, then that is the most appropriate form, and can be used in formal occasions. `じゃありません` can only be used in informal occasions. As for the politeness level, there is no difference between them.

Comment: @sawa: Are you sure じゃ (copula) and じゃ (in じゃない) are really different lexemes? Kansai uses /yà/ for both, which would be an odd coincidence if they're different.

Comment: They are indeed different; two words pronounced the same way can easily evolve the same way while having a separate etymology.