# じゃ meaning in a sentence

Tags: word-choice

フラットな心じゃ処理できない

What does the じゃ mean? Is it a particle?

Comment: Contraction of では.

Comment: @user3856370 colloquial I'm assuming?

Comment: see https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4578/what-is-%e3%81%98%e3%82%83-in-%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84 or https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30465/%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e6%84%8f%e5%91%b3%e3%81%8c%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-%e3%81%98%e3%82%83noun%e3%81%8c%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84